# How do I convert Gregorian date into Persian date (Jalali) in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, converters

I want to convert the Gregorian date to Persian in the following code

```
select  cast(dateGregorian as persianDate) date
from order
where orderid = ?
```

Comment: Select FORMAT(Getdate(), 'yyyy/MM/dd-hh:mm:ss', 'fa')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this solution

```
select  FORMAT(dateGregorian ,'yyyy/MM/dd','fa') date
from order
where orderid = ?
```

[image]